# Qt's opaqueresize property on QSplitter meaning

Tags: qt, qsplitter

I didn't find this on the web...

What does this `opaqueResize` property on QSplitter ([see doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qsplitter.html#opaqueResize-prop)) stand for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are asking here. It's all in the [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsplitter.html#details).

> QSplitter resizes its children
>   dynamically by default. If you would
>   rather have QSplitter resize the
>   children only at the end of a resize
>   operation, call setOpaqueResize(false)

Meaning if you set `setOpaqueResize(false)` on your splitter, start your application and try to pull the splitter to resize the widgets it holds it will not actually resize widgets until you release the splitter. On the other hand if it is set to `true` it will try to resize the widgets while you are dragging the splitter handle.

It can be useful to turn this feature off if your custom widgets take long time to draw for example since it would make resizing quite slow.

But to answer your question, property `opaqueResize` holds whether resizing is opaque or not, i.e. will it resize the widgets while dragging the splitter or not.

---

**Example:**

Here is a PyQt example you can try (I had example laying around in Python, but it should work the same in C++):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        top = QtGui.QLabel('test', self)
        bottom = QtGui.QPushButton('test', self)
        splitter = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        # Try changing from False to True
        splitter.setOpaqueResize(False)
        splitter.addWidget(top)
        splitter.addWidget(bottom)
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(splitter)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setGeometry(250, 200, 350, 250)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope this makes things a bit clearer.

Comment: Good explanation. In other frameworks, it may be called live resize.